# PS1 possibly making Bash text wrap to same line

Tags: bash, prompt

I just configured my .bashrc file (PS1) to get a fancier bash prompt and now I have an issue, all my text is wrapping to the same line in the terminal

[image]

here is my PS1:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\033[01;32m[\u]\033[01;00m╾\033[01;31m[\h]\033[00m\033[01;34m\033[01;34m[\w]\033[00m╼\033[09;31m $ '
```

any ideas on what I messed up? I'm happy with what the prompt itself looks like:

[image]

Comment: Without decoding your escape sequences, did you perhaps disable the line wrap of your terminal?  But why complain?  Think of al the space you have free in the window!

Comment: IDK what escape sequences do, tbh I don't know bash at all I just looked at ps1 and played with it till my bash prompt looked cool.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with bash, the escape codes are commands that are understood by your terminal.   Without knowing what terminal you're using, it'll be hard to help your.

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.0.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Can you read the first eight words of my previous comment?  If you click on "Help", then on "About ...", you may find out what terminal you are using.

Comment: Qterminal 0.14.1, sorry

Comment: see also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, it's not about the terminal.

Comment: oh I see, when I was playing with it I didn't use the "\" and I got parenthesis so i just removed the brackets, thanks a ton